# What is the difference between two initializers of NSManagedObject

Tags: swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

If somebody could please help me on what is the difference on creating an object of NSManagedObject subclass from these initialization methods:

[init(context:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobject/1640602-init)

vs

[init(entity:insertInto:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobject/1506357-init)

Thanks.

Comment: What is unclear about them after reading their respective documentation?

Comment: init(context:) states:

Initializes a managed object subclass and inserts it into the specified managed object context.

where as init(entity:insertInto:) states:

Initializes a managed object from an entity description and inserts it into the specified managed object context.

In code, with either, it returns an object of my NSManagedObject-subclass, no apparent difference. So should I rephrase my question, like what does it mean when it says: 

"Initializes a managed object from an entity description" vs "Initializes a managed object subclass". Please guide.

Answer (score 1):

It's about implicitly and explicitly specifying entity name so

```
guard let appDelegate =
    UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
        return
}

let managedContext =
    appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
```

1-  This will create an object from entity named `Person`  represented by class `CustomObj` and inserts it in `managedContext`

```
let entity =
    NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Person",
                               in: managedContext)!

let person1 = CustomObj(entity: entity, insertInto: managedContext)
```

2-  This will create an object from  class `CustomObj`  where entity name is `CustomObj` and inserts it in `managedContext`

```
let person2 = CustomObj(context: managedContext)
```

---

```
class CustomObj:NSManagedObject {

}
```